# How to connect Elasticsearch over HTTPS with Nginx as a reverse proxy server

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, proxy

I run Elasticsearch 5.0 on my production server.
I use Nginx as a reverse proxy server.
My website is secured with Let's Encrypt so I need Elasticsearch to run over `https` like this
`curl -XGET https://172.31.18.5..........` otherwise my site fails to receive data from Elasticsearch.
I've read [this post](https://www.ralphlepore.net/setting-up-basic-authentication-with-elasticsearch/) for setting up basic authentication for Elasticsearch with Nginx.
The post suggests configuration as the below.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name {{ your_search_domain }};
    rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name {{ your_search_domain }};
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     {{ ssl_dir }}/elasticsearch.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key {{ ssl_dir }}/elasticsearch.key;

   access_log {{ nginx_log_file }};
   error_log {{ nginx_error_file }};

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:9200 http://{{ your_search_domain }}/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        auth_basic "Search Authentication";
        auth_basic_user_file {{ nginx_htcontrol }};
    }
}
```

I have changed the parts surrounded by {{ }} but failed to run it over `https`.

It only accepts `http` like this `curl -XGET http://172.31.18.5...........`

Can I use the same Let's Encrypt certificate and key for `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` respectively?

Should `proxy_pass` be like `proxy_pass http://172.31.18.5:9200` ?

**My setups**

I have only one master-eligible data node in my cluster.

I set `number_of_shards` to 1, and `number_of_replicas` to 0.

The followings are the setups for my `elasticsearch.yaml`.

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/
cluster.name: MyAppName
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 172.31.18.5
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Comment: Is it possible that curl is not accepting your Lets-Encrypt certificate? Because your setup makes sense

Comment: My site runs under the certificate with no problem but I guess it's possible that elasticsearch doesn't accept it. I really don't know.

Comment: Hmm.. it might be possible that they JRE keystore that elastic search is using could be the issue (JRE 8 doesn't recognise Lets Encrypt as valid). However the issue you're having is Client-->Server right?

Comment: Yes, it's between client and server.

Comment: Hmm strange, your NGINX proxy sounds correct.... anything helpful in NGINX or ElasticSearch logs?

Comment: When I try to connect it over `http` it returns `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://172.31.18.5:9200/users/_suggest'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` When I try to connect it over `https` using the certificate, it just times out without producing any errors. But the data is stored into elasticsearch. I just can't retrieve the data over `https`.

Comment: You couldn't switch your `rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;` to `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`, because that's the syntax I always used and is used here: http://www.minvolai.com/blog/2014/08/Setting-up-a-Secure-Single-Node-Elasticsearch-server-behind-Nginx/Setting-up-a-Secure-Single-Node-Elasticsearch-server-behind-Nginx/ . I'm not too sure what rewrite does

Comment: It didn't work.